# Crawl log error on KB files- item was partially parsed. The item has been truncated in the index because it exceeds the maximum size

Tags: search, crawl

Due to some max download size errors in our Crawl Log, we recently upped our MaximumDownloadSize property size in our 2013 SharePoint environment to 100MB. However, now we're getting errors on KB files that are within the 100MB range.

Example on a 397KB file: 
**This item was partially parsed. The item has been truncated in the index because it exceeds the maximum size. ( Document 'abc.pdf' was partially processed. The parser was not able to parse the entire document.; )**

Any ideas as to why the smaller file would error?

Thank you!

Comment: check if if you have an embeded object on the file like an embbede image.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem where small .pdf files (less than 1MB in size) were being truncated. I finally found that it was version 1.3 .pdf files that were generated by SQL Server Reporting Services were the issues. I was able to resolve it by using the Adobe iFilter.

Details may be found here: http://messor.com/small-pdf-files-reporting-item-truncated-index-exceeds-maximum-size